# Prime and maximal ideals of this ring?

Tags: ring-theory

> $R=\bigl\{\frac{a}{b}\  |  \gcd(3, b) = 1,\ a, b ∈ \Bbb Z\bigr\}$

I am trying to find all of the ideals in this ring. So far I have $\bigl\{0\bigr\}$, $R$, and $S=\bigl\{\frac{a}{b}\  |  \gcd(3, b) = 1, \gcd(3,a)=3 \ a, b ∈ \Bbb Z\bigr\}$ . I'm not sure how to find any more or, if there are no more, show that this is the case. I am then interested in which of the ideals are prime and maximal.

Comment: Which elements of this ring are *not* units?  When you answer that question, you'll have an idea of some non-trivial ideals.  I don't think your set $S$ is an ideal because it's not closed under addition:  $2, 4 \in S$ but $2+4=6 \notin S$.

Comment: @RobertShore oops - it was meant to say gcd(a,3)=3. I have now edited to fix.

Answer (score -1):

This is the ring of fractions with denominator *not* divisible by $3$. In other words, it is the localisation of $\mathbf Z$ at the prime ideal $3\mathbf Z$, usually denoted as $\mathbf Z_{(3)}$.

It is known the only non-trivial ideals of this ring are generated by the powers of $3$, so the only prime ideals are $(0)$ and $3R$ (which is the single maximal ideal of $R$).

Comment: I wrote my $S$ down wrongly in my original post, but have now edited - is this equal to $3R$? I am quite new to ring theory and this is the first time I have met this ring.

Comment: Yes, your (corrected) ideal $S=3R$.  It's not hard to prove the result stated in this answer.  Prove that any non-trivial ideal $I$ must have *some* positive integer, and then consider the smallest positive integer in $I$.  Prove that smallest positive integer must have the form $3^k$ for some $k \in \Bbb Z^+$.  Then show that $I$ consists of $R$-multiples of that integer.